# Delegate in parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a bunch of methods that return List of GridTiles, for example GetTopNeighbour. I would like to be able to pass them to method AutoConnect using the GetNeighboursHandler delegate as a parameter.

```
    public delegate List<GridTile> GetNeighboursHandler(GridTile c);

    public List<GridTile> GetTopNeighbour(GridTile c)
    {
        //do stuff and return list
        return null;
    }
     public GridTile AutoConnect(GridTile c, GetNeighboursHandler del)
    {
        List<GridTile> tempList = del(c);

        // do stuff with the tempList
    }

    public void Test(GridTile c)
    {
        AutoConnect(c, GetTopNeighbour(c));
    }
```

In the Test method I get the error: ... cannot convert ...Generic.List...to GetNeighboursHandler. 
Have I completely misunderstood how delegates work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `delegate` (which is an object that knows how to call the method, ie: it holds the reference of a method)
What you have done is passing the function result that you get after it's execution
`GetTopNeighbour(c)` returns a `List<GridTile>`, and you are passing this return value in your code here

```
AutoConnect(c, GetTopNeighbour(c));
```

Instead you should pass the reference to that method `GetTopNeighbour`

```
AutoConnect(c, GetTopNeighbour);
```

Refer these [This is a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm) and [here's another one](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-delegates)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the method (or rather, method group) itself, instead of calling it:

```
AutoConnect(c, GetTopNeighbour);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the result of `GetTopNeighbour(c)`, which is a `List<GridTile>`, as a parameter to AutoConnect.

Instead, you want to pass the MethodGroup to be converted to a delegate, like so:

```
AutoConnect(c, GetTopNeighbour);
```